# Microsoft proxy server not working with CNTLM and apt-get

Tags: apt, proxy

I'm trying to connect an ISA proxy server with CNTLM. But syntax of ISA proxy looks different. I can't find a way to set proxy for apt. my CNTLM is listening on `127.0.0.1:41040`, and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` is like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy  "http://urmia.ac.ir\username:pass@127.0.0.1:41040/";
```

Which `urmia.ac.ir` is the domain of ISA in my university. I'm getting 407 error. CNTLM says

```
HEAD: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the username and password (in hashed form, preferably) in CNTLM's configuration file. Apt doesn't need to know your username and password.

Configuring cntlm can be a little finicky, you need to play around with "Auth" flags, until it works reliably. [Here's a howto](http://www.leg.uct.ac.za/howtos/use-isa-proxies) I wrote for users at my university.

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score -1):

You have to fill information in `/etc/cntlm.conf`.